# Can the output of an L298N be smoothed using a capacitor to reduce buzzing?

Tags: motor, dc, pwm, raspberry-pi

I'm running some model trains with a Raspberry Pi using L298N modules to control motor speed. Traditionally, this would be done using what is essentially a DC motor speed controller, but I need digital control over the output and this seemed the most sensible way to go.

The problem I'm facing is that the PWM signal is hugely amplified by the motor in the locomotives, and running is often clunky.

My understanding is that the H bridge is taking the PWM input and a voltage source, and producting a relatively bumpy DC output capable of driving the motors, which is amplified by the motor coils.

**So, to the question**, can the output of that H bridge be smoothed using a non-polarised capacitor? If so, what value and type of capacitor would be recommended given the circumstances?

It will likely be suggested that increasing the frequency outside of audible range will solve the problem but as far as I can tell, the RPi4 peaks at 8kHz. Having tried a few values as low as 50Hz up to 8kHz, I can't find any frequency where the noise is much subdued. At around 100-300Hz it's very quiet, but running is incredibly lumpy and the locomotive inches along a bit at a time.

My concern is mostly around whether the L298N is monitoring its output in some sort of feedback circuit - I don't really know how they work, and don't want to risk letting the smoke out of something.

Comment: If you just put a capacitor directly across the output, there will be huge transient currents flowing through it. Treat it like a switching power supply and also put an inductor between the output and the capacitor.

Comment: I think you are on the right track - you need a higher PWM frequency.  The processor you are using is running its PWM module at 100MHz, so you should be able to get to 20-30 Khz or so with plenty of resolution for your speeds.  You may have to dive a little deeper into your firmware.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks, are you able to link to a circuit diagram of what would be expected? I've dealt with basic components but inductors are somewhat new to me.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead The RPi spec says 8kHz max - where are you getting 100MHz? It's possible I guess that they simply don't expose it to the user, maybe to conserve resources? I need to run 3 of these from a single board so if I'm going to need a whole core per controller it might become problematic.

Comment: The PWM section of https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/bcm2711/bcm2711-peripherals.pdf talks of a "serialized version of a 32-bit word" clocked at 100 Mhz (chapter 8).  It looks like you can load and serially clock out 64 32-bit bitstreams or a PWM configuration at 100 MHz.  Looks like there are only two independent PWM channels, so maybe you are running a "soft" PWM which would account for it being so low-frequency.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead Amusingly, this seems likely to lead me to the same problem I suffered with Arduino - even on the Arduino MEGA there are only 2 PWM outputs. I'm currently operating 3 controllers, and ideally I'd like to be able to add up to 10 more (rough guess, not certain of anything yet). Very odd that the 100MHz is not available in the standard library. I would have to guess the Pi people have limited it for a justifiable reason, although I'll try to find more detail on why it's not available. Thanks for the info - especially pointing me at the chapter.

Comment: If you want to keep from getting too deeply into the hardware, you might consider a full-bridge driver with built-in PWM generation capability.  Allegro makes a number of products in this line and their cost would be comparable to the L298.